# Android: What is different between Intent Action Reboot and RebootCompleted

Tags: android, android-intent, reboot, android-reboot

I saw these two different actions. I mostly used RebootCompleted which the system reboot completed but there is a delay before these action was sent to the receiver. Does the Reboot will be sent inbetween the phone gets started and rebootCompleted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no Reboot Completed intent. You most likely mean `android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED`. This is action **broadcasted** by system to listening apps, once the system completed booting, which allows i.e. Calendar app to re-set alarms etc.

`Intent.ACTION_REBOOT` from other hand is a broadcast to have the system rebooted. But user apps cannot send it normally, yet if you'd be privileged app, then as result system should reboot.

So despite name similarities, these are completely different things. However once `Intent.ACTION_REBOOT` is fired successfully and device completed reboot, `android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED` will be broadcasted

Comment: Opps sorry you are right... Thanks for the clarification. No wonder if I use Intent.Action_Reboot in my broadcastReceiver, it doesn't get called.

Comment: That's quite possible :)